# Query to get which stores are open

Tags: sql, rdbms

I have a text table of each store and its working days and hours. What tables would I need to create to make a query to check which stores are open?

| StoreId | OpeningHours |
| --- | --- |
| 153 | Sunday 9-15, Monday 8-12, Tuesday 7-10 |
| 189 | Monday 9-18, Tuesday 7-19, Thursday 11 - 19 |
| 191 | Monday 9-16, Wednesday 7-19, Friday 11 - 19 |

Comment: Please provide more details and strucutre of your table with sample data. Also,desired result will be beneficial.

Comment: MySQL and SQL Server are *completely* different products; only tag the RDBMS you are *really* using.

Comment: Are those OpeningHours really stored as varchar? That makes it easy to display, but almost impossible to work with

Comment: @Hans Kesting Yes, i believe they can be stored as a varchar. Here is the question about design of the tables and which query could extract the storeIds of the open stores

Comment: Just because they can be stored as a varchar, doesnt mean they should. I would really recommend splitting them out into different columns like days of the week and then a 1 or 0 to show if the store is open that day.

Comment: What is the 1 question?

Answer (score 1):

This can be, for example,

```sql
CREATE TABLE timetable (
    timetable_id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    store_id INT,
    week_day TINYINT,
    hrs_from TINYINT,
    hrs_till TINYINT,
    CHECK (week_day BETWEEN 0 AND 6),
    CHECK (hrs_from BETWEEN 0 AND 23),
    CHECK (hrs_till BETWEEN hrs_from + 1 AND 24)
);
```

The absence of overlapped rows should be checked by the trigger.

Comment: Not sure what question you're answering, as the OP didn't provide any specific issue, and they didn't show any work - just some data and an open-ended opinion-soliciting question about what to create.

Comment: @DavidMakogon *Not sure what question you're answering* I answer the question asked explicitly: "What tables would I need to create to make a query to check which stores are open?". Taking into account the data sample provided.

Comment: The OP asked others to do their work. They've shown no sample output. They've shown no queries. Just... asking others to build a schema for them. And this isn't how Stack Overflow works. You wrote more code than the OP (who wrote zero code). The issue is that a lot of people post assignments here, and then wait for others to answer their questions without them doing anything specific.